# Various Summarized Dates in One Table or View - SQL Server v14

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m using SQL Server v14 and am trying to create a summary view or table (Im a SQL novice so go easy on me). I’ve attached some example data from which I’d like to create another table that has the following columns (below).

I'm having trouble summarizing more then one date field into one table since the "where" statement would only capture one of these. How do I create more then one summarized column in a table? How do I create more then one WHERE field for each column?

Example Data column headers (Input)

```
USID|      Job_Desc|    Grouping Designation|     hoursdate|    hours
USBUGBY    None         DIRECT                    1/21/2019     5    
US76546    None         DIRECT                    12/31/2018    6
US76546    None         DIRECT                    12/31/2018    6
US73546    None         CTE                       2/28/2019     6
US73546    None         CTE                       2/28/2019     6
```

Desired Output:

```
USID    MTD Hours    Rolling Hours    Current Month Hours
```

Column Logic

- USID
- MTD Hours - Prior Month, so if today is 2/1 it should show January
- Rolling Hours - -12 month to Prior Month
- Current Month Hours - Current Month (so if today is 1/21, this would be all of January)
- Next Month Hours (Ex: February)

Comment: There is no SQL Server 17.9. The latest release is Version 14.0, and the preview is version (2019) is 15. I suspect your looking at your SSMS version which is completely different to the version of your SQL Server. You can get the version of your SQL Server by running the command `PRINT @@VERSION;`. In relation to your data, don't post it as an image; it isn't helpful to any of the volunteers you're asking help from. Post it as formatted `text`, or ideally as DDL and DML statements. When do Edit your post, please also don't forget your expected results and the attempts you've made. Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing you mean the version of SSMS. This is not the same thing as the server. The challenge here though is that you haven't actually asked a question. Here are a couple places to look. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks! I've added a question, updated the version and replaced the image with formatted text.

Comment: Well, you've specified input, but not your desired output. Guessing what you want from the bullet points is a little too hard.

Comment: Good point. I've made it more clear what I'm looking for

Comment: If you could show your desired results as a dataset, that would clear any confusion (and don't forget those attempts I asked for please; you may well almost have the solution and we just need to give you a nudge). Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion - change the `2/31/2019` dates in your sample to `2/28/2019` so cut-and-paste coding won't blow up on illegal dates.

Comment: Good point. Fixed February dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to easily get the multiple summaries into different columns is to use subqueries. For example:

```
DECLARE @dt date
SET @dt = '20190201' -- Easiest if this is set to the 1st of the current month
                     -- Otherwise, calculate the 1st of month.

SELECT
    USID
    (
        SELECT Sum(hours) 
        FROM MyTable mt
        WHERE mt.HoursDate >= DATEADD(Month, -1, @dt) 
            AND mt.HoursDate < @dt
            AND mt.USID = m.USID
    ) Prior_MTD_Hours, -- Prior Month, so if today is 2/1 it should show January
    (
        SELECT Sum(hours) 
        FROM MyTable mt
        WHERE HoursDate >= DATEADD(Month, -12, @dt) 
            AND HoursDate < @dt
            AND mt.USID = m.USID
    ) Rolling Hours, --12 month to Prior Month
    (
        SELECT Sum(hours) 
        FROM MyTable mt
        WHERE HoursDate >= @dt 
            AND HoursDate < Dateadd(Month, 1, @dt)
            AND mt.USID = m.USID
    ) Current Month Hours, -- Current Month (so if today is 1/21, this would be all of January)
    (
        SELECT Sum(hours) 
        FROM MyTable mt
        WHERE HoursDate >= DATEADD(Month, 1, @dt) 
            AND HoursDate < Dateadd(Month, 2, @dt)
            AND mt.USID = m.USID
    ) Next Month Hours 
FROM MyTable m
```

This is the basic framework of what you are looking for. Obviously, you will add any other grouping you need into the inner queries as well.

There are other ways this could be done as well, such as using the subqueries as derived tables:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Mytable m
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT USID, Sum(hours) as PriorMthHrs
        FROM MyTable mt
        WHERE mt.HoursDate >= DATEADD(Month, -1, @dt) 
            AND mt.HoursDate < @dt
        GROUP BY USID
    ) as mp
    ON mp.USID = m.usid
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT USID, Sum(hours) 
        FROM MyTable mt
        WHERE HoursDate >= DATEADD(Month, -12, @dt) 
            AND HoursDate < @dt
            AND mt.USID = m.USID
        GROUP BY USID
    ) as mr
    ON mr.USID = m.usid
....
```

These example fragments should give you the basic format you need to do this.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!